# How to setup the Imputer as part of sklearn pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, data-preprocessing

I am working on the Titanic dataset and I wish to handle all the preprocessing activities on a pipeline. So, here is my code:

To get the dataset

```
!wget "https://calmcode.io/datasets/titanic.csv"
```

And then read it as below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

dt = pd.read_csv("./data/titanic.csv", index_col=["PassengerId"])
```

And then I setup a single pipeline which is suppose to preprocess the numerical features:

```
numerical_features = ["Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare"]
numerical_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[("min_max_scaler", MinMaxScaler()),
                                     ('num_imputer',SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')])
```

Then fit the pipeline:

```
column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('numeric_transformer', numerical_pipeline, numerical_features),remainder='drop')

column_transformer.fit(dt)
transformed_dt = column_transformer.transform(dt)
```

But, I need to apply the `Imputer` only in the `Age` feature and not in all the other columns.Currently, it applies the imputer over all the columns.

My question is :

How can I specify that I need to apply the `SimpleImputer` ***only on the Age*** column and not in all of the `numerical_pipeline` ?

Comment: do you want to scale frist and impute in the seconds step?

Comment: no, i think, it should be the other way around. First average and then scale.

Comment: In that case, I would just make a pipeline that first imputes on the age column and passes through columns "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare" and in the second step after that ColumnTransformer you add the MinMaxScaler

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use two column transformers, so if you set up the minmax this way:

```
minmax = ColumnTransformer([(
"minmax",
MinMaxScaler(),
["age", "sibsp", "parch", "fare"])
],remainder='drop')
```

The output comes without column names, but based on the column names we input, age will be the first, so:

```
imp = ColumnTransformer([(
"impute",
SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean'),
[0])
],remainder='passthrough')
```

Then into a pipeline:

```
Pipeline([("scale",minmax),("impute",imp)]).fit_transform(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have said in a comment, you want to first impute and second do the scaling. In that case, I would first create a column transformer that only imputes the one column, passes through the three others numerical columns, and drops columns that are not part of that set. After that, you add a MinMaxScaler on the output of that column transformer. In code

```py
ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ("num_imputer", SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="mean"), ["Age"]),
        ("needed_columns", "passthrough", ["SibSp", "Parch", "Fare"]),
    ],
)
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[("transform", ct), ("scale", MinMaxScaler())])
```

The important bit here is that you add a second entry to the list of transformers, that has the word "passthrough" and specifies all the columns that should be passed through without any modifications.

Comment: But, this would not work when our data has categorical values, right? In such scenario (with numbers and categories) how can we make the imputer in a pipeline?

Comment: I've been struggling with this one for a while, and I don't think it's really possible to apply multiple transformations to the the same specific variable w/o it impacting all others and not have to use index to reference it. You can't both impute and scale only Age w/o impacting other var.